# Is there a trade model which takes in account credulity?

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-modeling, economics

I have to admit I'm not to familiar with mathematical economics but, as a student in mathematics, I was trying to play a bit with a toy trade model I'm try to build over a finite population.

My feeling is it would be interesting to introduce a factor "credulity" or "naivety" for each member of the population having an effect in the trading process.

Do you know if there is already a way (i.e. a function) suggested to take in account such a variable ?